# Missed session variables when redirecting page

Tags: session, laravel-5.1

I have a problem regarding sessions in Laravel. I try to redirect the page and at the same time sending some session variables using the `with()` method:

```
return Redirect::To('/')->with('foo','bar');
```

But when the page comes up, the only session variables set are `_token` and `locale`, 'foo' and 'bar' do not appear. Running `{!! var_dump(Session::all()); !!}` gives:

```
array(2) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "l5NawtJdHJtanTErsya440UvPQIgqNExiryJIkIO" ["locale"]=> string(2) "se" }
```

The session stored in `storage/framework/sessions` strangely has other variables set, such as `url` and `PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA` that don't show up when redirecting.

Now, here's the real twist: It works perfectly when run on a different computer.

We tested with the same repository, same code, a fresh installation of laravel, same web browser, same OS (Mac) and same program for running the server locally (MAMP). On another computer it works fine, and on a third computer, but not on mine.

The application is in debug mode and I have tried clearing all caches in Laravel and in the browser nothing changed.

Does anyone have a clue on how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in `config/session.php` the variable `domain` was set to the production domain. So when using localhost on my computer, the cookie `laravel_session` couldn't be read or written.

It worked by using:

`'domain' => null,`

Answer (score 0):

`with()` method use to pass data to a view. If you want to add something to session use `session()->flash->('foo', 'bar');`(automatically erase after next request) or `session()->put('foo', 'bar');`

Comment: I have tried out to use the put() method, but that doesn't seem to work either. I rather think it's something wrong with the setup. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: What's the output of this `session()->put('foo', 'bar'); dd(session()->has('foo'));`

Comment: So It means there are no issues with sessions. use `put()` or `flash()` method to add data to session

Comment: But when running `session()->put('foo', 'bar')` in the controller and `dd(session()->has('foo'));` in the view, it says "false". So there seems to be some problem with the redirect.

Comment: Try this, add `session()->put('foo', 'bar'); sleep(2);` to controller and then call it from view `dd(session()->has('foo'))`